# Minimizing maximum cost in an one-to-one assignment problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, game-theory

I want to compute a one-to-one assignment, from A to B where A and B have n elements. Each element of A will be assigned to one element in B. There is an associated cost between each element of A and B. The goal is to minimize the maximum cost of the assignment.

How to compute such an assignment using the cost matrix? I need to select an element from each row/column such that minimax strategy is achieved.

I was able to achieve this by listing all possible assignments and calculating their maximum costs and then selecting the one with the least maximum cost, but I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: You're looking for a "minimum cost matching in a complete balanced bipartite graph" -- searching using these terms should give you good results. bipartite means you have 2 sets of vertices with edges between them. Balanced means these sets are the same size. Complete means that all edges between the two sets are present. A matching is a set of edges s.t. each vertex is on at most one edge.

Comment: https://homes.di.unimi.it/righini/Didattica/OttimizzazioneCombinatoria/MaterialeOC/11%20-%20Min%20cost%20bipartite%20matching.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably as a MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model:

```
 min z
 z >= c[i,j]*x[i,j]   ∀ i,j
 sum(i, x[i,j]) = 1   ∀ j
 sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1   ∀ i
 x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

This can be solved with any MIP solver.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force polynomial cost algorithm based on repeated application of max matching in bipartite graph:

Order the pairs by assignment cost. Take `n` cheapest pairs. This determines a bipartite graph with `A` and `B` as vertices (pairs are edges). Try to find a matching in this graph. If found, it determines the optimal one-to-one assignment.

If not found, add the next pair. Repeat until a matching is found.

I suspect this can be optimized by not running the matching algorithm from the start every time you add an edge but rather keeping the maximum matching and checking if it can be augmented with the newly added edge.

Comment: If you squint, this is sort of what the Hungarian algorithm is doing, but the extra complexity in manipulating the dual solution is what makes it correct.